# Spring MVC returns a blank page

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, error-handling, modelandview

In my project, I have a requirement to handle user POST request and fill the results into an `iframe` (called `result_frame`).

- When POST request data is valid, I return a view to fill the `result_frame` as `ModelAndView(myviewName)`
- When POST request data is invalid, I want to fill the `result_frame` with a blank page.

Is there any simple way to return a blank page without creating a separate `View` for it? (e.g. `ModelAndView("_blank")`)

Comment: no you have to create a blank page for that.

Answer (score 1):

Go for this code, It will return a blank page as u wish...

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println(" ");